# Why some fields are not fitrable via a bool query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I used to think I knew how to use bool queries but what I was doing before does not seem to work anymore: **some fields can be filtered via a bool query, while some other cannot.**

*(I am testing on V6 so maybe something changed in the meantime but [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) does not seem to suggest so)*

The query

```
GET /security-center*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

outputs documents such as

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1487073,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "security-center-2019.01.24",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "igzyfWgBcCggV6jwR96k",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "vulns_port" : "49666",
          "hosts_vulns_scanners_0_loadavg" : "0.0",
          "vulns_patchpubdate" : "-1",
          "vulns_description" : "This script uses WMI to list the processes running on the remote host\nand listening on TCP / UDP ports.",
          "hosts_vulns_completedchecks" : "3046410",
          "vulns_family_id" : "20",
          "hosts_vulns_repository_description" : "CREATED",
          "hosts_vulns_completedips" : "30",
          "hosts_vulns_ownergroup_id" : "0",
          "hosts_vulns_ownergroup_name" : "Full Access",
          "host_dmz" : "False",
(...)
```

I will query for two of the fields above: `vulns_port` and `hosts_vulns_ownergroup_name`, taking bool conditions exactly from the document above.

#### Case 1: `vulns_port` (OK)

I want to get documents where `vulns_port` is `49666`:

```
GET /security-center*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": { "vulns_port" : "49666" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "took" : 83,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4142,
    "max_score" : 5.9115334,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "security-center-2019.01.24",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "PKT0fWgBHaYvxmURB5eY",
        "_score" : 5.9115334,
        "_source" : {
          "vulns_port" : "49666",
          "hosts_vulns_scanners_0_loadavg" : "0.03",
(...)
```

#### Case 2: `hosts_vulns_ownergroup_name` (KO)

I want to get documents where `hosts_vulns_ownergroup_name` is `Full Access`:

```
GET /security-center*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": { "hosts_vulns_ownergroup_name" : "Full Access" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "took" : 18,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you join your mappings? We need to know how your fields are indexed to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on ES6, try to use the `.keyword` sub-field instead:

```
GET /security-center*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": { "hosts_vulns_ownergroup_name.keyword" : "Full Access" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you are fast ;)

Comment: Oh yes yes yes - `.keyword` - that one already bit me once before so now I will remember. Thanks!